# reshape data with repeated and alternating column names

Tags: r

I am a beginner  with R, and I would like if someone can walk me through this issue. I have a data set with three variable x, y, z and many rows. The variables repeat every year in columns for 45 years as follows:

```
Country   X1970  Y1970  Z1970  X1971  Y1971  Z1971 X1972  Y1972  Z1972  ..
Algeria    10     23     13     54     15     86    57     82     49    ..
Albania    90      8     17     16     55     64    39     26     71    ..
Angola     34     43     49     92     89     33    90     23     49    ..
```

I want to reshape the data so that it looks like this:

```
Country    Year     X     Y     Z
Algeria    1970     10    23    13
Algeria    1971     54    15    86
Algeria    1972     57    82    49
......     ....     ..    ..    ..
......     ....     ..    ..    ..
......     ....     ..    ..    ..
Albania    1970     90    8     17
Albania    1971     16    55    64
Albania    1972     39    26    71   
......     ....     ..    ..    ..
......     ....     ..    ..    ..
......     ....     ..    ..    ..
Angola     1970     34    43    49
Angola     1971     92    89    33
Angola     1972     90    23    49
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are usually better off submitting questions that don't have anything to do with statistics to the other message boards (e.g. stack overflow), but since I do this all the time, I'll answer it for you.  This should work for you and should be very easy to do.  I'm sure there is probably a better way to do this, but I just whipped it up for you without much thought:

```
> country<-c("Algeria", "Albania", "Angola")
> X1970<-c(10, 90, 34)
> Y1970<-c(23, 8, 43)
> Z1970<-c(13, 17, 49)
> X1971<-c(54, 16, 92)
> Y1971<-c(15, 55, 89)
> Z1971<-c(86, 64, 33)
> 
> mydf<-data.frame(country=country, X1970=X1970, Y1970=Y1970, Z1970=Z1970,
+ X1971=X1971, Y1971=Y1971, Z1971=Z1971)
> mydf
  country X1970 Y1970 Z1970 X1971 Y1971 Z1971
1 Algeria    10    23    13    54    15    86
2 Albania    90     8    17    16    55    64
3  Angola    34    43    49    92    89    33
> 
> library(reshape)
> newdata <- melt(mydf, id.var="country", variable_name="VarName")
> newdata$Year<-substr(newdata$VarName, 2, length(newdata$VarName))
    > XData<-newdata[grep("X", newdata$VarName),]
> YData<-newdata[grep("Y", newdata$VarName),]
    > ZData<-newdata[grep("Z", newdata$VarName),]
> names(XData)[3]<-"X"
> names(YData)[3]<-"Y"
> names(ZData)[3]<-"Z"
> newdata<-merge(merge(XData, YData, by=c("country", "Year")), ZData, by=c("country", "Year"))
> finaldata<-newdata[,-c(3, 5, 7)]
> finaldata<-finaldata[order(finaldata$country, finaldata$Year),]
> finaldata
  country Year  X  Y  Z
1 Albania 1970 90  8 17
2 Albania 1971 16 55 64
3 Algeria 1970 10 23 13
4 Algeria 1971 54 15 86
5  Angola 1970 34 43 49
6  Angola 1971 92 89 33
>
```

Comment: This also can be done with SAS easily

Comment: Well it can be done with any program.